# Documentation proposal problem

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-proposals

Recently I proposed a new topic in the documentation's HTML section.

Hours later another user proposed the same idea without looking at current queue and his version got approved.

I don't have a problem with the fact that the accepted proposal wasn't mine, I only have problem with the fact, that the currently accepted topic was less detailed than what I made (it doesn't contain a remark section for example).

Comment: I think drafts should be able to be marked private :(